# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.login_jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, tomcat7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHHbh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtzZV.png)

I've followed all the troubleshooting steps suggested on Stack Overflow, including comparing project settings, verifying library versions, inspecting system environment, performing a thorough code review, and testing external dependencies. However, I'm still encountering errors that my colleague doesn't, even though we have the same versions of code, dependencies, Eclipse, server, and Java. The project is using Tomcat 10.1, Spring Boot 6, and Jakarta. What could be the reason for these discrepancies?

Comment: The abovelinked dupe answers the problem in 1st screenshot. The problem in 2nd screenshot is just a consequence.